# Pytorch visdom: can`t start visdom

Tags: pytorch

When I run `python -m visdom.server`, then it shows:

```
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
    logging.error('Error {} while downloading {}'.format(exc.code, key))
AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'code'
```

What does it mean? How can I deal with it?

Comment: The URL you hit seems to be invalid (name resolution). Try printing it and then curl to see whether the server responds.
Also, when you say `it shows: enter code here`, does that mean you need to add code? I'd suggest improving formatting to clarify your question.

Comment: I didn`t describe my question clearly, but always thank you so much.